# IIS suddenly gets access denied when attempting to read web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-6

We have an intranet legacy app that is 95% replaced, but unfortunately the 5% is still necessary and not yet implemented in the new system.  One of the remaining functions accesses a piece of data in the `<appSettings>` section of the `web.config` file and today I was told that the data needed to be changed.

I went in as we have done many times before, copied the `web.config` to the server’s desktop, made a backup copy, edited the appSettings key, and then copied the `web.config` back out to the site’s location on the server.  Instead of updating as it always had before, now the site is unreachable and returns only the following error:

[image]

I’m fairly certain that it really can’t read the `web.config` file, because the web.config has customErrors turned off, but when accessed from outside of the server, it gives the generic IIS “Runtime Error” message, with the instructions on turning off customErrors.

I’m at a real loss here, because that change to a non-configuration piece of data seems to have broken the whole thing.  Putting back the original copy did not fix the problem.  No permissions or other settings have changed in months (and have all been verified to still be the same as they should be).  I have been unable to Google-up anything useful related to this problem.

Comment: In IIS, go to your Application Pools, and click on the right Application Pool for your Website and click on "Advanced Settings" and see what identity it is running under - is it NETWORK_SERVICE or Application Pool Identity? Also what .NET framework version is the Application Pool set to? Is it the correct one as specified in your project?

Comment: It is running under a service account.  I tested that, and the service account is still working correctly.  This is IIS6... it's not giving me any options to see what .NET version the app pool is running, but none of that has changed.  It has always been running the same .NET version as the application, 4.0.30319.

Comment: LocalService or Network Service? If NetworkService, then grant full permissions for the Inetpub folder to the Network Service User. Without actually having access to the server, anything else would be speculation, but I'd advise you to take a look at this thread - http://forums.asp.net/t/1298192.aspx - a lot of the suggestions there seem logical, especially as it relates to older versions of IIS. It'll be a permissions thing at the end of the day.

Comment: Did you copy or move this file back into your website's folder? Check the permissions of the `web.config` and compare them to an existing file on the site.

Comment: OK, so it did turn out to be the permissions on the `web.config` itself.  I had been busy checking all the folder permissions and forgot that the file itself could be wrong.  Still weirds me out though, because I've done this exactly this way numerous times w/o incident, and all of a sudden it breaks it...